# Instantiated delegate's reference?

Tags: c#, multithreading, pointers, reference

```
private void ShakeWindow()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(/* ref to this instantiated method? */), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    // shake window
                }
            }));
         thread.Start();
    }
```

Can I pass a reference the point above? How? Or Are there any better solution to invoke controls? I know I can do this with following:

```
private void ShakeWindow()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShakeWindowThread));
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void ShakeWindowThread()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(ShakeWindowThread), null);
        }
        else
        {
            // shake window
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass an `Action` delegate.. You need to elaborate on what the question really is about.

Comment: There is no easier way to reference the method you're in, unfortunately. You'll have to do it like you've done it in the second code sample. Though, and this is only my preference, I would add a `return` after you call `this.Invoke(...);` and drop the `else` part, it makes for a prettier method.

Comment: Is there any point in starting a thread that doesn't do anything but try to run code on the UI thread again?  Use a Timer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks. Any difference between mine and yours (with return)?

Comment: None, but ponder the question asked by Hans above, though I assume (hope) this is demo code to show the problem, and not the entire production code.

Comment: @HansPassant It's being called from a thread that is responsible for TcpListener, listens clients etc. and I will add Thread.Sleep(secs) for shaking window , I don't want to sleep in listener's thead so thats why I create a new thread.

Comment: So you really *do* want to use a Timer.  You still have to BeginInvoke() to start it.